# NoSuchMethodError . The method 'map' was called on null. (Flutter )

Tags: flutter, dart

Exception has occurred.

NoSuchMethodError :

> NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
> Receiver: null Tried calling: iterator

I'm getting the above error when running the code. its seems like I'm receiving the error in the line .map inside the main.dart files below :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './Queston.dart';
import './Answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var question = [
      {
        'questionKey': 'who is your friend?',
        'answer': ['Jermmy', 'hanna', 'steve', 'lee yu']
      },
      {
        'questionKey': 'where are you from ',
        'answer': ['berlin', 'newyork', 'paris']
      },
      {
        'questionKey': 'what is your  job',
        'answer': ['teacher', 'doctor', 'driver']
      }
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("AppBar"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(question[_questionIndex]['questionKey']),
            ...(question[_questionIndex]['answerkey'] as List<String>)
                .map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
            }).toList() // Answer(answer),
            // Answer(answer),
            // Answer(answer),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

below is my answer dart files :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectAnswer;
  final String answer;
  Answer(this.selectAnswer, this.answer);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: selectAnswer,
        child: Text(
          answer,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Question dart code has shared below :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String question;
  Question(this.question);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Text(
        question,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data has no key `answerKey`, if you observe your data, you have kept the key as `answer`, changing that will solve the issue

Correct Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './Queston.dart';
import './Answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var question = [
      {
        'questionKey': 'who is your friend?',
        'answer': ['Jermmy', 'hanna', 'steve', 'lee yu']
      },
      {
        'questionKey': 'where are you from ',
        'answer': ['berlin', 'newyork', 'paris']
      },
      {
        'questionKey': 'what is your  job',
        'answer': ['teacher', 'doctor', 'driver']
      }
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("AppBar"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(question[_questionIndex]['questionKey']),
            ...(question[_questionIndex]['answer'] as List<String>)
                .map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
            }).toList() // Answer(answer),
            // Answer(answer),
            // Answer(answer),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```